# React: How to update state in an array requiring remote calls for each item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to develop a dashboard type application which has a number of "tiles", each displaying a single value representing a reporting metric.The tile definitions (title, etc) are read from a single JSON file at runtime. The report metric values however, require 1 remote API call per tile. This gives the user the experience of the tiles displaying immediately with the report metrics filling in as they are resolved. I'm having trouble modelling this in React. Here's a simplified version what I have so far...

```
// tile info object
export interface ITileData {
  title: string;
  value: number;
}

// tile component
export interface IDashboardTileProps {
  tileData: ITileData;
}

export class DashboardTile extends React.Component<IDashboardTileProps, any> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>{ this.props.tileData.title } = { this.props.tileData.value }</div>
    );
  }
}

// container component
const TILE_DEFS: ITileData[] = this.getTileDefsFromJson();

export interface ITileContainerState {
  tiles: ITileData[];
}

export class TileContainer extends React.Component<any, ITileContainerState> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tiles: TILE_DEFS
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    // load tile values
    this.state.tiles.map((tile, index) => {
      // *** THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ***
      // I need to make an HTTP API call for each tile to get its value
      // I don't want to call setState in a loop like this, but I do 
      // want the values to appear when they are resolved, not all at 
      // once when all of the HTTP calls are resolved.
    });
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <List
        items={ this.state.tiles }
        onRenderCell={ tile =>
          <DashboardTile tileData={ tile } />
        } />
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you can't use 1 API call for fetching all data due to bad client-server design, it'd still be better to call the API from within each tile so they would set their own state.

Comment: Take a look into Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar before and the way went about it was:

`this.state.tiles.map` should return an array of `<Tile>` components, you then need to make a `Tile` component that takes in all its needed parameters for both display and api calls. All the parent container does is provide it the props it needs to make its own api calls and manage its own state.

The benefits to this are being able to isolate those state updates to that component, have it render a loader/some sort of "I'm waiting to get results back" kind of interface per tile, and it will also display the data as soon as it gets the api back so you dont have to wait for all of them to finish.

to pseudocode:

```
this.state.tiles.map((tile, index) => {
 return <Tile {...tile} />
}

class Tile extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { fetching: true, data: null } 

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // make api calls here
    doApi().then((result) => {
      this.setState({fetching: false, data: result})
    });

  }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the typescript or whatever you are using so this is just plain ol' react and obviously missing pieces but should give you the general sense of the idea.

Comment: I had a feeling I was going to have to move the API calls down to the tiles. Seems like that's the way to go.